# How to run fasttext in metaflow?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, installation, fasttext, netflix-metaflow

I am trying to use fasttext in metaflow, but I cannot install it successfully. I use pip_install_module("fasttext", "0.9.1") to install. The error message in metaflow is:

[image]

Usually, I install fasttext in AWS sagemaker like shown below:

[image]

It works this way.

So how to install fasttext in metaflow?